# building a Map from 2 arrays of values and keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I wonder if there is an easy way to build a Map from an Array of keys and an Array of values.
for exemple if I have 2 Arrays

```
var keys = [0, 4, 2, 3, 1];
var values = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"];
```

and I intend to obtain this Map :

```
{
  0 => 'first',
  4 => 'second',
  2 => 'third',
  3 => 'fourth',
  1 => 'fifth' }
```

of course I'm looking for something quicker than:

```
var myMap = new Map();
for (var i = 0 ; i < keys.length; i++)
myMap.set(keys[i], values[i]);
```

because it's O(n) and i seek something O(1)

Comment: I don't think this can be done in O(1), but I could be wrong.

Comment: if there are no hash value collisions and you don't need to worry about key order, you could use FastMap: http://www.collectionsjs.com/fast-map

Comment: You have `n` values you want to add the Map. No matter what you are doing, a map cannot set `n` values simultaneously.

Comment: It's not possible to have O(1). But, you can have better than O(n). BTW, if one of the arrays indexes are numbers and starts with 0 and is ordered, you can simply use indexOf (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) and map it at the time. No need extra map

Comment: You already have O(0) why do you need to convert ie `values[keys[0]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (does not work on every user agent).

> The **`Object.assign()`** method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
var sum = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"],
    obj = Object.assign({}, sum);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: oh, how nice, a dv, please add your motivation, if you like.

Comment: How does your answer address the question of building "a Map from an Array of keys and an Array of values"? Also, Object.assign copies all properties using getters and setters, so it cannot be better than O(n).

Comment: *"I'm looking for something quicker than [...] because it's O(n) and i seek something O(1)"*. its a question with two parts. my answer addresses the first part. the second is quite unclear, because it relies on implementation.

Comment: Thanks Nina for the method  **assign()** i ignored. I changed the order of the Array  **keys** (in my question) to be be clearer about what i seek. Sorry fo having been previously ununderstandable

Comment: Yes but in this case I will be O(n)

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript ES6, there is no way to build a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from an array of keys and values with better run-time complexity than **O(n)**.

If you had a combined key-value array, you could pass it as the first parameter to the Map() constructor:

```
var map = new Map([[1, 'first'], [2, 'second'], …]);
```

With two separate arrays for keys and values, however, adding them one-by-one per for-loop is still your fastest option.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can always do things like this in O(1); in which you don't copy the properties one by one and get an object.

```js
var values = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"],
       obj = Object.create(values);
console.log(typeof(obj));
console.log(Array.isArray(obj));
console.log(obj[2]);
```

Comment: It seems many people here confuse the number of high level function calls with the number of instructions that determine the run-time complexity.

Comment: @le_m It seems you are very knowledgeable. Could you please explain me the complexity of creating an empty object and assigning an array to it's prototype..? To me this answer is totally legit and very fast O(1). Given the OPs conditions (indices as properties) it's perfectly suitable for a map as well.

Comment: You are right, according to http://mrale.ph/blog/2014/07/30/constructor-vs-objectcreate.html on V8, the Object.create() implementation is indeed in O(1) - my comment should go to the OP's question, not your answer (sorry for that)! However, how does your answer address OP's problem of mapping given keys to given values?